# Sending a template to multiple people without knowing their email in sendgrid

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, sendgrid

I need to send an email to multiple users who's email i don't know.

```
exports.sendgridMail =
  functions.database
    .ref('/inviteNewMembers/{id}/recipients/{email}')
    .onCreate(event => {
      sgMail.setApiKey('api key');
      const msg = {
        to: ['recipient1@example.org', 'recipient2@example.org'],
        templateId: 'template',
        dynamic_template_data: {
          subject: 'invited_team_name',
          text: 'link_to_onboarding'
        }
      };
      sgMail.send(msg)
```

Database:

[image]

I need to add the array of emails from recipients into the TO

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to send a mail to all the emails under the `/inviteNewMembers/{id}/recipients/` node each time a new email is added to this node (i.e. a new sub-node of the `recipients` node is created).

The following code should do the trick:

```
exports.sendgridMail = functions.database
  .ref('/inviteNewMembers/{id}/recipients/{email}')
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {

    emailsRef = snap.ref.parent; //We define the Reference of the parent node

    return emailsRef.once('value').then(dataSnapshot => {  // We read the values of the parent node
      const emailsArray = [];
      dataSnapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
        emailsArray.push(childSnapshot.val());
      });
      console.log(emailsArray);
      const msg = {
        to: emailsArray,
        templateId: 'template',
        dynamic_template_data: {
          subject: 'invited_team_name',
          text: 'link_to_onboarding'
        }
      };
      return sgMail.send(msg);  //Very important: we return the promise returned by the send() method
    });
  });
```

In addition to the comments in the code, you should note the following points:

1. By doing `.onCreate(event => {})` you are using an old syntax, for Cloud Functions versions <= v0.9.1. You should modify your code (to `.onCreate((snap, context) => {})`) and update your libraries, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff
2. We return the promise returned by the Sendgrid's `send()` method. I would suggest you watch the 3 videos about "JavaScript Promises" from the Firebase video series: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/, in order to understand why this is really important.

Comment: @SlavikLeskiv Hello, did you have the opportunity to look at the proposed solution?